# Access 2016 IIF (more that 2 conditions)

Tags: microsoft-access

I need help I need correction in the code below. I have 3 conditions that need to be met. If all 3 are met then give me the word `"Active"` if not, give me the word `"Inactive"`.

```
Expr1: IIf([Master COA STATUS]="Active" AND [Active / Inactive]="Active" AND [Paylocity and GL DEPT]="Active","Active","Inactive")
```

Comment: Your code looks correct to me - what is the issue?

Answer (score 0):

Here is my example SQL statement for the query:

```
SELECT Tabelle1.ID, Tabelle1.[Master COA Status], Tabelle1.[Active / Inactive], Tabelle1.[Paylocity and GLDept],
IIf([Master COA Status]="Active",IIf([Active / Inactive]="Active",IIf([Paylocity and GLDept]="Active","Active","Not Active"),"Not Active"),"Not Active")
AS Ausdr1 FROM Tabelle1;
```